# C++ OpenCV SetMouseCallback to a different window

Tags: c++, opencv

Is it possible to modify the function `cv::setMouseCallback` so that it responds to a different window when you have multiple windows shown at once?

I tried using `cv::setMouseCallback("image_window", NULL, NULL);` and setting it to a different window, but it did not work for the second window I tried to draw on.

Comment: Can't you set a callback for each window?

Comment: When I tried doing that with multiple windows shown at once, simply clicking on another in the background causes my program to think that I'm dragging my mouse for some reason, so now I'm editing each window one at a time.

Comment: Why you need to do that? What does your program do?

Comment: I can't disclose that information, I'm doing research at a hospital.

Comment: yeah.. I didn't mean that. What I meant, are you trying to make up a simple GUI or something? Because that's not the work for OpenCV

Comment: No, I'm just creating matrices that I can easily open and close in a number of windows and use GrabCut, so it'll have to be in OpenCV

Comment: so basically you work on a single window at a time? If so, you probably simply need to correct your underlying logic..

Comment: are you using Windows/Visual Studio?

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to work on multiple at once but since that wasn't working in my program, I'd open another window when the one was closed. Terminating the program and rerunning it for each window isn't an option. I'm working with VS 2013.

Comment: well, 2 options come in mind. 1) don't close the window when you finish to draw your suff for grubcut, but update with the new image and continue. 2) if you need multiple images at the same time, put them (eventually resized) inside a single image, so you can work on multiple images at the same time. Then your clicks won't correspond to the real coordinate of your images, but with simple geometric consideration you'll know which image was clicked, and where...

Comment: If you havn't done it yet, download and install the VS extension [Image Watch](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_visual_studio_image_watch/windows_visual_studio_image_watch.html)

Comment: I'll definitely try that, thanks!

Comment: Remember that if you need something more that a very simpe GUI, you should do it for example in Qt. You can use Qt in VS or in QtCreator, and do your processing in OpenCV as well.